# Calling Back-End Java Class from a JSP

Tags: java, asp.net, jsp, jakarta-ee

I come from a .NET back ground and just started working with Java. I found Java SE to be no problem since they closely follow the same concepts. However, when working with Java EE I found it to be a little bit more complicated than ASP .NET.

I am trying to implement the N-Tier architecture in a Java EE application. So I have already written my Logic & Data layers and tested them successfully in a Java SE application (which is my Administration back-end application) and have just started working on my Display layer.

Here comes the question. I am trying to call my business logic layer from JSP (Triggered by a button event) to invoke a certain method and return the result output (boolean for example) to the JSP.

**How do I do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can do all in jsp . use JAVA **MVC Framework**

even without that u can perform simple backhand operations using **Servlet**
or else you can use **Java Beans** which is simple business logic implementation 
example for java beans please reffer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm

example for **Servlet** is given below

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="add" method="post">
        Value 1:<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/><br>
        Value 2:<input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br>
        </form>
        <%String sum="";
         sum = (String)request.getAttribute("val3"); %>
        <input type="text" value="<%=sum%>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.add</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**add.java**

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class add extends HttpServlet {
    String val3;
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String val1=request.getParameter("val1");
        String val2=request.getParameter("val2");
        if(val1 != null && val2 != null)
        val3=""+(Integer.parseInt(val1)+Integer.parseInt(val2));
        else
        val3="";
        request.setAttribute("val3",val3);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response); 

        try {
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're reply and link pretty much explained everything.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET this kind of things handeled by .Net (javascripts and other things inserted in page by .Net) but in java, you must write them yourself. In .Net you have some javascript method like `do_postback` but in java you should write javascripts. See this code:

Script:

```
<script>
function doPostback() {
    // calling some java method using Ajax or Http Post method or redirect to another page
}
</script>
```

Html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="doPostback()">Go</button>
```

Comment: I understand that Java requires more "actual" programming than .Net. But can I avoid typing any actual code in the JSP itself? Like in .Net just the function name in the code file? For example, this is how I add a class in my JSP to be used inside the page.<jsp:useBean id="businessLogic" scope="application" class="com.app.ticket.business.DataBusinessLogic" /> Now how do I associate the methods inside this class with say a button?